# Can "Dans la balance" be used the same as "in the balance"?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

For example... HANGS IN THE BALANCE: an issue (especially a dynamic between two extremes) of importance that may be decided one way or the other?
Also... IT'S ALL IN THE BALANCE: success in XXXX depends on having good balance

Comment: Have you looked in dictionaries ? [in the balance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/in-the-balance), [it hangs in the balance](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/it+hangs+in+the+balance.html). Why didn't what you found help you?

Answer (score -1):

No, in French the metaphorical idea of equilibrium *is* associated with the word "*balance*" (balance des pouvoirs, balance des paiements, balance commerciale, ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/balance)); however, the idea in "hang in the balance" is "incertitude".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/balance)  II.− P. métaph. ou au fig. [Implique la not. de jugement ou d'équilibre]

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/balance_1?q=balance)) (be/hang) **in the balance**
> ​if the future of something/somebody, or the result of something is/hangs in the balance, it is not certain.

As to "IT'S ALL IN THE BALANCE", where "balance" is taken literally as "the ability to preserve balance of one' body", "balance" would be translated rather as "sens de l'équilibre".

- C'est purement dans le sens de l'équilibre.

> (SOED) **balance** **11** Stability due to equilibrium between the forces within a system; (ability to maintain) steadiness of position; *transf.* mental stability.

Comment: Regardez juste https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/it+hangs+in+the+balance.html cité par None, pour un échantillon de traductions possibles.

Comment: @Frank Il n'y a qu'un sens de « hang in the balance » ([WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/hang%20in%20the%20balance), [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-hang-in-the-balance)), et ce n'est pas celui que vous lui donnez. Reverso est parsemé de signe de « danger » (Vous comprenez ?) (1/2)

Comment: @Frank  Ensuite, on ne traduit pas un passé par un présent. En fait, votre traduction n'est que du non-sens : « être dans le sens de l'équilibre » ne signifie rien en français. On peut dire « **aller** dans le sens de l'équilibre » mais ça n'a rien à voir avec « hang in the balance ». (2/2)